# Redirecting django URLs

Tags: python

I am trying to link the pages in a django application. when i have Home/about on my navigation

after i go to about page, when i click on home again the url is home/about/home

how do i change it just to about?

path('home/about/', views.about, name='Database-about'),

http://localhost:8000/home/about/about

Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/home/about/about

Using the URLconf defined in Main_DB.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
home/ [name='Database-home']
home/about/ [name='Database-about']
home/login/ [name='login']
home/login/MetaData/ [name='Database-form']
home/about/login/ [name='login']
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to redirect to an absolute page instead of relative, put a leading slash before the URL. Example:

```
/admin/
/home/
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you. but it doesn't work. This is the error that it shows WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W002) Your URL pattern '/about/' [name='Database-about'] has a route beginning with a '/'. Remove this slash as it is unnecessary. If this pattern is targeted in an include(), ensure the include() pattern has a trailing '/'.

Comment: Do not put a leading slash in your urls, instead put it in the link. You cannot make urls absolute at the django side, you have to fix your links.

Comment: Thank you, It works now. that was simple yet hard to find out